# Automatically deserialize to string-like class in Web.API controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web.API endpoint that takes an object like this as a parameter:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public UserName UserName { get; set; }
}
```

For example:

```
[Route("api/person")]
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public void UpdatePerson(Person person)
{
    // etc.
}
```

*(This is just an example - we're not actually accepting usernames through our Web.API endpoint)*

Our `UserName` class is an object that defines implicit operators to `string`, so we treat it exactly as we would a `string` throughout our application.

Unfortunately, Web.API doesn't automatically know how to deserialize a corresponding JavaScript `Person` object into a C# `Person` object - the deserialized C# `Person` object is always null.  For example, here's how I might call this endpoint from my JavaScript frontend, using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/test',
    data: { FirstName: 'First', LastName: 'Last', Age: 110, UserName: 'UserName' }
});
```

If I leave off the `UserName` property, the `data` parameter is correctly deserialized into a C# `Person` object (with the `UserName` property set to `null`).

**How can I make Web.API properly deserialize the `UserName` property on the JavaScript object into our custom `UserName` class?**

---

Here what my `UserName` class looks like:

```
public class UserName
{
    private readonly string value;
    public UserName(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public static implicit operator string (UserName d)
    {
        return d != null ? d.ToString() : null;
    }
    public static implicit operator UserName(string d)
    {
        return new UserName(d);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value != null ? value.ToUpper().ToString() : null;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(UserName a, UserName b)
    {
        // If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.
        if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
            return true;

        // If one is null, but not both, return false.
        if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
            return false;

        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(UserName a, UserName b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if ((obj as UserName) == null)
            return false;
        return string.Equals(this, (UserName)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        string stringValue = this.ToString();
        return stringValue != null ? stringValue.GetHashCode() : base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have sample Json being sent, because that object should be wrapped in another `{ }`

Comment: How do you call your Web API, show code.

Comment: That is not valid json. The property names should be surrounded with "-characters. `{
    "FirstName": "First",
    "LastName": "Last",
    "Age": "110",
    "UserName": "UserName"
}`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Added an example jQuery.ajax() call.

Comment: Could you post the `UserName` class? I suspect the problem is that while C# handles `UserName` like a string, the deserializer will only deserialize a JS object into a C# object.

Comment: @peco - You're right, I've updated the question to remove references to JSON and replaced them with examples of how I am sending the data as a JavaScript object using `jQuery.ajax()`.  Perhaps JSON isn't even involved - I'm not sure what format the JavaScript object is being serialized to before it's sent to my Web.API.

Comment: Try `$.param({ FirstName: 'First', LastName: 'Last', Age: 110, UserName: 'UserName' })` this.

Comment: @Mourndark - I've added the implementation of my `UserName` class at the end of the question.

Comment: The problem is in your `class UserName` it hasn't any accessible property setter and parameterless constructor.

Comment: You are passing just a string as UserName, but on the back-end you have a super complex class. .Net can't map to that!

Comment: @jpgrassi - That's exactly my question.  I'm assuming I can define a custom deserializer for that class that knows how to convert a simple string into my custom `UserName` class?

Comment: Why do you want to map a simple string to a complex class like that? Wouldn't be much easier to just define it as a string and inside your c# code you handle yourself the UserName Class?

Comment: @jpgrassi - If this was an isolated use-case, I agree - it would be much easier to just take in the `UserName` property as a string and convert it inside my controller.  But I'm hoping to find a fool-proof way to do this kind of conversion globally for *all* my Web.API controllers so that developers can simply ask for a `UserName` class and the deserialization process will take care of that plumbing automatically.

Comment: As @jpgrassi suggests, you could use a ViewModel to receive the values into your controller, then convert them into your domain models. You could use something like AutoMapper to setup the mappings and reduce boilerplate.

Comment: @NathanFriend, this `UserName` class will become a serious "wtf?!" for every programmer working on that code. You put a lot of effort into making it look and act like a `string`, yet I can see no additional behavior that justifies using it in place of a simple `string`. When you add a `JsonConverter` things will become even worse. Nobody want's to debug convoluted stuff like that.

Comment: Totally agree with @Abbondanza. Ideally you should simply change your UserName property to string type in your viewmodel and use that as needed.

Comment: @Abbondanza - The main reason we have this type of class is for type safety. Our application is built on a legacy system that uses three different kinds of usernames.  It's very important that we don't accidentally call a method that's expecting one type of username with a different type of username.

Comment: @NathanFriend, in that case nevermind my objections. Type safety seems critically important in such a scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a custom [Json.NET Converter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for your `UserName` class. After you create the custom converter then you need to tell Json.NET about it. In one of my projects we added the following lines of code to the `Application_Start` method in your `Global.asax.cs` file to let Json.NET know about the converter:

```
// Global Json.Net config settings.
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () =>
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    // replace UserNameConverter with whatever the name is for your converter below
    settings.Converters.Add(new UserNameConverter()); 
    return settings;
};
```

---

Here is quick and basic implementation of one that should work (untested). It almost certainly could be improved upon:

```
public class UserNameConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var username = (UserName)value;

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("UserName");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, username.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Variables to be set along with sensing variables
        string username = null;
        var gotName = false;

        // Read the properties
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.PropertyName)
            {
                break;
            }

            var propertyName = (string)reader.Value;
            if (!reader.Read())
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Set the group
            if (propertyName.Equals("UserName", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                username = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
                gotName = true;
            }
        }

        if (!gotName)
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException("A username must be present.");
        }

        return new UserName(username);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(UserName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for - do you have an example of an implementation of the `UserNameConverter` class?  I've tried similar things with no luck - the conversion methods are never triggered.

Comment: @NathanFriend I would need more information to know why the conversion methods aren't triggered. My guess is your `CanConvert` method is matching the wrong type.

Comment: Yes, this process did work for me!  I'm using a different implementation of the `JsonConverter`, but the idea is the same.  The issue I was running into was that my `.ajax()` calls didn't have a `contentType` of `application/json; charset=utf-8`.  I've documented this solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34404269/1063392

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest striving for more separation of concerns.

You have two concerns here:

1. Handling HTTP requests and responses.
2. Performing domain logic.

WebAPI is concerned with handling HTTP requests and responses. It provides a contract to consumers specifying how they can consume its endpoints and actions. It shouldn't be concerned with doing anything else.

### Project Management

Consider using multiple projects to separate concerns more clearly.

1. `MyNamespace.MyProject` - Class Library project that will hold your domain logic.
2. `MyNamespace.MyProject.Service` - WebAPI project that only contains your web service.

Add a reference to `MyNamespace.MyProject` on `MyNamespace.MyProject.Service`. This will help you maintain a clean separation of concerns.

### Different Classes

Now, it's important to understand that you will have two classes with the same name, but are different. Fully qualified, their distinction becomes clear:

1. `MyNamespace.MyProject.Person` - Your domain layer representation of a Person.
2. `MyNamespace.MyProject.Service.Models.Person` - Your WebAPI contractual representation of a Person.

Your domain layer object:

```
namespace MyNamespace.MyProject
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public UserName UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your service layer object:

```
namespace MyNamespace.MyProject.Service.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        //The service contract expects username to be a string.
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The benefit here is that the domain layer representation can change independently of the WebAPI contract. *Thus, your consumers contract does not change.*

### Isolate Domain Logic From Service Logic

I'd also suggest moving any domain logic that acts upon the incoming `Person` to your domain logic Class Library. *This also allows this logic to be reused in other applications and libraries that may be outside the scope of WebAPI.* Additionally, to continue with separating our domain logic from our service logic, I'd implement the Repository pattern, and create `MyNamespace.MyProject.PersonRepository` defining how to deal with your repository of domain level `Person` objects.

Your controller may now simply look like this:

```
[Route("api/person")]
[HttpPost]
public void UpdatePerson(Models.Person person)
{
    var mappedPerson = Mapper.Map<Person>(person);
    personRepository.Update(mappedPerson);

    //I'd suggest returning some type of IHttpActionResult here, even if it's just a status code.
}
```

The magic with `Mapper.Map<Person>(person)` comes from [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). You'd first setup your mappings in a configuration class somewhere at application start. These mappings would tell AutoMapper how to convert `MyNamespace.MyProject.Service.Models.Person` into `MyNamespace.MyProject.Person`.

```
//This gets called once somewhere when the application is starting.
public static void Configure()
{
    //<Source, Destination>
    Mapper.Create<Models.Person, Person>()
        //Additional mappings.
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Username, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new UserName(src.UserName)))
}
```

Furthermore, you'd likely need to use either a Singleton, Service Locator, or Inversion of Control (IoC) container like Ninject to get a reference to your `personRepository`. I strongly suggest using IoC. Ninject has a package that can take over the creation of controllers for WebAPI, injecting your dependencies that you have configured.

What we have accomplished here is that we have moved all the domain logic out of `MyNamespace.MyProject.Service`. `MyNamespace.MyProject` may now be tested independently, or even included in other projects without bringing along the WebAPI dependencies. We have achieved a clear separation of concerns.

---

#### Note on Class Naming

*The identical class names can be confusing to some teams.* You may choose to implement some type of naming convention to make the names more clear, like appending `DTO` or `Model` to the classes in your service layer. I prefer just placing them in different namespaces and qualifying them as needed.

---

#### Third Party Libraries Referenced

1. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) - For reducing boilerplate in mapping service objects to domain objects, and vice-versa.
2. [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) - For injecting dependencies into controllers (remember to get the WebAPI or OWIN packages too). Any IoC can be used. Alternatively, a Singleton or Service Locator pattern could also be used, but may make testing difficult.

Neither of these libraries is required to follow the ideas of this answer, but can make life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

WebAPI can serialize and serialize typed structure. What you have to do though is follow the typed pattern. For example in Javacsript I can create an object like Person

```
var person = {
userName: 'bob123',
firstName: 'Bobby',
lastName: 'Doe'
}
```

Then pass that as an object as part of my request to webAPI

In webAPI have the type defined as:

```
[Route("api/membershipinfo/getuserdata")]
[HttpPost]
 public IHttpActionResult DoSomething([FromBody]Person p)
 {
   try
     {
       ...rest of your code here
```

If you have the .net Type `Person`  and it matches what you created in your javascript request name/property wise it will be available for mapping.

Note on the casing. I follow the camelCasing pattern so the first character is always lowercase. In your dot net type you don't need to do this WebAPI will allow you to account for this via configuration.

How I accomplished it was with a custom configuration formatter in my webapi.config which helps convert the type during serialization

```
    //source: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization
    // Replace the default JsonFormatter with our custom one
    ConfigJsonFormatter(config.Formatters);

}
private static void ConfigJsonFormatter(MediaTypeFormatterCollection formatters)
{
    var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
    var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
    settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that his `Person` object has declared the `UserName` property as type `UserName` but he is giving it a `string` instead.

Comment: If that is the case it can be resolved by introducing a light weight DTO that can allow him to pass a more lightweight object into the API call.  Then handle the mapping into a more complex type either in WebAPI or in a secondary DTO layer

Comment: That would be my suggestion as well. Use a ViewModel to accept values into your controller, then use a mapper like AutoMapper to convert them into the objects you need for your domain logic. After all, WebAPI is just plumbing for accepting and responding to requests served via HTTP.

Comment: It's sounding like this might be what I need to do.  I was hoping that I could customize the deserialization process to accomplish this, but I may be stretching what Web.API was designed to do.