# Custom Json.NET JsonConverter is not being called while deserializing Web.API parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web.API endpoint that takes an object like this as a parameter:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public UserName UserName { get; set; }
}
```

For example:

```
[Route("api/person")]
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public void UpdatePerson(Person person)
{
    // etc.
}
```

I've defined a custom JsonConverter to convert from a JSON string property to my custom `UserName` class:

```
public class UserNameJsonDeserializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(UserName);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new UserName((string)reader.Value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }
}
```

I've added this `JsonConverter` to my global list of `JsonFormatters` in my `Global.asax`:

```
// Automatically dsserialize JSON strings to UserNames
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new UserNameJsonDeserializer());
```

When I send a request to my Web.API, the `CanConvert` and `ReadJson` methods are never called.  This is how I'm calling my Web.API endpoint front my JavaScript frontend (using jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/person',
    data: { 
        FirstName: 'First', 
        LastName: 'Last', 
        Age: 110, 
        UserName: 'UserName',
    },
});
```

**Why is my custom `JsonConverter` being ignored by Web.API?**

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ - Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean you answered your own question? Is it some sort of tip article?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ - See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Oh I see, encountered this thing for the first time. :)

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ - No worries! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making your jQuery `.ajax()` call, you need to send you data as JSON, otherwise the Web.API won't call any JSON-related converters while deserializing the data.  Try adding a JSON `contentType` and `JSON.stringify`-ing your `data` parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/person',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 
        FirstName: 'First', 
        LastName: 'Last', 
        Age: 110, 
        UserName: 'UserName'
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```